# Debug into libraries in python

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.7, pycharm

I'm trying to enter library function in PyCharm, to see what is happening there, but I can't: debugger shows me details and variables, moving inside step by step, but I don't see on my Window lines of code. I just can feel debugger is moving over them because it shows different internal variables. 
I guess that happens because library is installed as binary package, without sources.

How should I install library to be able moving by it using debugger?

I tried both this installation types:

- I installed pip, and using it successfully installed suds.
- I also downloaded suds sources (and build&installed from them, using setup.py).

And both don't show me internal codelines. How can I move using debugger over library code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

After building suds using setup.py, there appears directory **suds** with sources in: **BUILDING_DIR\build\lib**

It needs to copy it to **C:\PythonXX\Lib\site-packages**

and remove from there **suds-Z.Z-pyX.X.egg**

then debugging starts to import sources from that directory and show code lines in debug. Bingo!

Comment: Such a manipulation (manually copying files into `"C:\PythonXX\Lib\site-package"` is mostly sign of broken installation environment or misunderstanding of installation procedures. I did it many times in past until I learned using `setup.py`, `pip` and occasionally `easy_install` properly. The biggest help was using `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`.

Comment: Yes, that is way of cheating on installation procedure, but do you know another way to let debugger know about code lines and show it right way?

Comment: I am working in Ubuntu and using command line debugger (`pdb` or `ipdb`) and never had problem with stepping through installed packages, if they were written in pure Python. Just now, I have tested `jinja2` rendering and I can step into it.

Comment: btw, I have found fantastic tutorial on command line debuger at [PMoW](http://pymotw.com/2/pdb/). Personally, I have stopped using IDE (used PyDev) as it was hiding real interaction with the tools.

Comment: It shows me how debugger works :-) still, it don't allow me to move by code of .egg installation, I don't know why.

Comment: Do you have similar problems with other packages too? I will not manage testing it with suds and with jinja2 it worked very well.

Comment: have you tried to install via `pip install -e package` when you got a local copy of your package? That should be the standard way